# How to use margin to center elements without erasing the older value of margin top and left?

Tags: html, css

Is there is any way to use margin auto to center the elements without erasing the older values of the margin top and bottom? notice that they are unknown.

I tried to make the margin left and right auto and it worked, but I want to know if there is any way to do it in one line, something you can write instead of 0 that keeps the older value

```
<style>
  .test {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 200px;
  }
</style>
<div class="test">this is test div</div>
```

It does work here but is there is any way to do it using margin by writing in the margin top and bottom a value that keeps the older value without knowing it?

Comment: no, the only way is the one you already done

Answer (score 0):

Create another div and put your code into this.. Please check below:
I have removed margin css.

```css
  .test {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: grey;
    width: 200px;
  }
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
<div class="test">this is test div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
      <style>
        .parent {
            display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
        }
        .test {
          background-color: grey;
          width: 200px;
        }
      </style>

    <div class="parent">
       <div class="test">this is test div</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The asnwer is no, you cant do that. You are using the one and only correct way of doing so.